# How to properly update Google Analytics Unity plugin

Tags: android, google-analytics, unity-game-engine

I have a game for Android with GAv3 installed, if I update Google Analytics to version 4 the game starts but I get some exceptions. Here's a log from Android Device Monitor:

```
03-15 16:06:44.906: I/Unity(17009): AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics
03-15 16:06:44.906: I/Unity(17009): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics
03-15 16:06:44.906: I/Unity(17009):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
03-15 16:06:44.906: I/Unity(17009):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
03-15 16:06:44.906: I/Unity(17009):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
03-15 16:06:44.906: I/Unity(17009): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics
03-15 16:06:44.906: I/Unity(17009): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/com.app.game-1/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/asec/com.app.game-1/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
03-15 16:06:45.286: I/Unity(17009): AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics
03-15 16:06:45.286: I/Unity(17009): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics
03-15 16:06:45.286: I/Unity(17009):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
03-15 16:06:45.286: I/Unity(17009):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
03-15 16:06:45.286: I/Unity(17009):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
03-15 16:06:45.286: I/Unity(17009): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics
03-15 16:06:45.286: I/Unity(17009): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/com.app.game-1/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/asec/com.app.game-1/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

I tried installing the plugin directly, thus letting Unity overwrite the files, and deleting the files by myself and installing afterwards. In both cases I get these errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy **play-services-analytics-8.4.0.aar** from {android-sdk}\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services-analytics\8.4.0 to your **Assets/Plugins/Android** folder. It worked for this [person](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1144993/androidjavaexception-javalangclassnotfoundexceptio-1.html) and may work for you.

Comment: New error: 
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format. See the Console for details.
C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_71\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "L:\Programs\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command;
 at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:122)

And goes on.

Comment: Solved using your answer and doing what stated [here](https://github.com/googleanalytics/google-analytics-plugin-for-unity/issues/51#issuecomment-98633184) afterward.

Comment: What file? If you are taking about **android-sdk}\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services-analytics\8.4.0** you need to download android sdk and set it up with Unity. You should create a new question instead of posting on a solved one. http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-sdksetup.html

Comment: Why **8.4.0**.  Wasn't that an outdated version?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky This post was made when the version was 8.4.0. You should substitute whatever the current version is now in the solution.