# Google Analytics Unity throws ClassNotFound since upgrade to play-services-analytics-9.4.0.aar

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-analytics

Google Analytics V4 was working well in my Unity project linking with play-services-analytics-8.4.0.aar. I've now upgraded to the latest Play Services including play-services-analytics-9.4.0.aar. I can build an apk successfully but calls to Google Analytics fail:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics"

I also tried adding libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar from the git project (a long shot) but that made no difference.

Advice?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of play-services-analytics-9.4.0.aar, copy play-services-analytics-impl-9.4.0.aar. But you may still need play-services-analytics-9.4.0.aar for some of the analytics feature. If you want to be sure, copy both.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is this is related to [Unity Google Analytics v4 works for Editor and iOS, not for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36748452/unity-google-analytics-v4-works-for-editor-and-ios-not-for-android)

Having spent a day on it, I'm just removing Google Analytics for now; hopefully there will be an update to the Unity Google Analytics plugin that makes it compatible with Google Play 9.4